# Returning ArrayList size does not work

Tags: java, arrays

When I run this program, it does not return anything yet no errors occur. I'm trying to create a method that will return the number of words I previously entered into the array once I enter "".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayCounter {
    public static int CountItems(ArrayList<String> list ) {
        int i = list.size();
        return i;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Hey gimme a word");
            String word = input.nextLine();
            if (word.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("The number of values entered were:");
                break;
            } else {
                Names.add(word);
            }
        }
        CountItems(Names);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning someting is not the same as printing it, therefor you must include `CountItems(Names)` in your print statement

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable and method names in *camelCase* and class names in *PascalCase*. In particular, `names` and `countItems`.

Comment: Also note that you do not even have an array in your code. `ArrayList` is a `List`, not an array. It uses arrays internally, thus the name.

Comment: `int result = CountItems(Names)` would do the trick, then print that result variable. I have voted to closed since this is just an incomprehension in the language and will not help future seekers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the result returned from `CountItems`.

The `println` should be:

```
System.out.println("The number of values entered were: " + CountItems(Names));
```

As an aside, methods names in Java should start with a lowercase, so `CountItems` should instead be `countItems`.

Comment: https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part1/week-3/
Exercise 61 says not to use print though, is there another way or is it simply poorly presented like you can show the value when you run the code?

Comment: @Anton the exercise says not to print `list.size()` inside `CountItems` but instead return it then print it, like we're doing now. if you want the number on a new line then simply do `System.out.println("The number of values entered were: \n" + CountItems(Names));`, there is no need to perform two separate `println` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CountItems` method returns the item count, but you are ignoring the result. You need some kind of `System.out.println(CountItems(Names))` to print the result to the console.

Also, please consider renaming `CountItems` to `countItems` and `Names` to `names` to follow the naming conventions for Java.